# Viewing model properties inside Umbraco template

Tags: .net, umbraco

This should be simple enough question but I am having problems with it, I am trying to enable disable sidebar in umbraco template based on Model's property.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="MainContent" runat="server">
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
@{
    boolean enableSidebar = Model.GetProperty("enableSidebar").Value;
}
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="@(enableSidebar ? "span9" : "span12")">
            <div class="default-content">
                <!-- CONTENT -->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (enableSidebar) { 
            <div class="span3 box">
                <div class="green-header-box"></div>
                <div class="inline box-content"> 
                    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="SidebarContent" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
</umbraco:Macro>
</asp:content>
```

I am getting error that says I cannot use asp tags inside macro which is fine, but I do not know how to do I achieve same effect without using macro, can you please help me re-write this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used in-line macros before but I would have thought it would have been something like:

```
@{
    if(Model.enableSideBar) {
        //DoSomething
    }
}
```

You need to reference the node you are on and then its property.